# How to disable personal teams in Laravel / Jetstream when using Inertia?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I followed an article here:

https://devlan.io/disabling-personal-teams-in-laravel-8-and-jetstream-1fd083593e08

Basically to disable personal teams in Laravel / Jetstream. Now the article gives the example of how to achieve this using Livewire but I am using Inertia. The Livewire template needs this to be changed from this:

```
@if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures()
```

To this:

```
@if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures() && Auth::user()->isMemberOfATeam())
```

How would I achieve this in Inertia? I have had a look around the web, but because I am new to this stack I am completely stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional made in Blade templates. Since Inertia doesn't work with Blade, instead it uses some JavaScript framework (Vue, React, Svelte), what you need to do is to run this conditional somewhere in the Laravel side (Controller, Middleware) and set a variable that you'll pass your client side component to conditionally render the teams html stuff.

**If you want to have this flag available to all the pages in your app, you can do this through the `HadleInertiaRequests` middleware.**

```php
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'has_teams' => Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures() && Auth::user()->isMemberOfATeam()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then, your component, you can use that variable to render the teams part or not (Example using Vue):

```html
<div v-if="$page.props.has_teams">
 <!-- Teams... -->
</div>
```